# argparser - add positional argument with choices specifying only the value directly

Tags: python-3.x, scripting, arguments

I want to add a positional argument to a python3 script to get the following usage:

```
script.py list test
script.py list dev
script.py list prod
```

Where:

- list = my command that i have done with a subparser
- test/dev/prod a positional argument called "env" which only has those values if defined, but defaults to another value if one of the desired values is not provided

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
parser_ls = subparsers.add_parser('ls', help='Lists running simulations in the current project', add_help=False)
parser_ls.add_argument('env', type=str, nargs='?', choices=['test', 'dev', 'prod'], default='no_env' )
```

But "env" takes the value of list now ( the first string i provide ).

How do i achieve what i want?

PS, reason i am doing subparsers is cause i have more than one commands and more than one custom help menu.

Thank you in advance!